# redis accumulate & publish a set of operations

Tags: redis, publish, node-redis, redis-sentinel

Is it possible to instruct Redis to accumulate a set of operations and then issue a "publish all"  command to publish the entire set of operations ( in linear order ) ?

So you'd somehow set a marker ( `startpublish` ? ) and a cache would accumulate all operations ( `hdel` `hset` ) received from that point on.

Finally you'd issue a command ( `publishall` ? ) and Redis would then broadcast the commands in linear order received.

IMPORTANT NOTE: I need to perform set-operations programmatically in Node.js, via Redis Sentinel Client ( package `redis-sentinel-client` ).

Answer (score 0):

You can queue multiple commands to redis using the `multi` and `exec` redis command.

So essentially what you end up with is something like this:

```
redis > multi
redis > set foo bar
redis > set alpha beta
redis > exec
```

What you get back is an array, in the same order you execute the commands. So the result set at index 0 of the resulting array will contain the error and/or result of the command `set foo bar`.

Example for the multi command can be found here: http://redis.io/commands/multi

Comment: thanks for the response.  Is `multi` `exec` only available via Redis CLI ?  I need command(s) that can be sent from a Redis client - such as Redis Sentinel Client.  ( I have amended my original question to reflect this. )

Comment: The docs for the package you mention suggests that `sentinelClient` is just like any other regular redis client. So yes, I think the above should work fine. 

I use https://github.com/mranney/node_redis which supports the multi and exec commands. Check for the support on the lib you're using.